# xctk:IntegerUpDown borderbrush does not show color

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpftoolkit

I tried to set color to the border of xctk:IntegerUpDown control with the following code.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:IntegerUpDown}" >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
</Style>
```

The BorderThickness shows correctly but the border color does not show as specified.
I must have missed something. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you use version below 2.0.0. This problem was solved with version 2.0.0.

Version 2.0.0 you can download [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/99072).

Below is code snippet when you can see that in version below 2.0.0 is missing binding to  template BorderBrush (`BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"`).

Version 2.0.0 implementation ([source code](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/NumericUpDown/Themes/Generic.xaml)):

```
<Style x:Key="NumericUpDown" TargetType="{x:Type prim:InputBase}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:ResourceKeys.ControlNormalBackgroundKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static themes:ResourceKeys.ControlNormalBorderKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
  <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
  <Setter Property="WatermarkTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultWatermarkTemplate}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
           <local:ButtonSpinner x:Name="PART_Spinner"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                AllowSpin="{Binding AllowSpin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                ShowButtonSpinner="{Binding ShowButtonSpinner, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">

               ...
```

Version 1.9.0 implementation ([source code](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/97685#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/NumericUpDown/Themes/Generic.xaml)):

```
<Style x:Key="NumericUpDown" TargetType="{x:Type prim:InputBase}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
      <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
      <Setter Property="WatermarkTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultWatermarkTemplate}" />      
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
               <local:ButtonSpinner x:Name="PART_Spinner"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    AllowSpin="{Binding AllowSpin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    ShowButtonSpinner="{Binding ShowButtonSpinner, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
        ...
```

Comment: Kmatyaszek, Thanks you so much. I was using 1.8.0. Downloaded the new version. Everything works fine now. Appreciate it.